# sqlsrv does not support named parameters to queries

Tags: sql-server, linux, php-7

I'm using PHP7 (with Droctrine 2.5.13) on Ubuntu 16.04 x64.
I'm trying to do a prepared statment to a Microsoft SQL database using a named variable like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER"
             FROM
                "PRODDB"."PRODUCT"
             WHERE
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER" LIKE :productNumber
             ORDER BY 
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER" DESC';

$query  = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query  ->bindParam(':productNumber' , $ofSearch);
$status = $query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

But SQL tell me that I need to use question mask instead of the named parameter

Error : *sqlsrv does not support named parameters to queries, use question mark (?)*

If I replace the named variable by a question mark it work fine.
The example below work fine:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER"
             FROM
                "PRODDB"."PRODUCT"
             WHERE
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER" LIKE ?
             ORDER BY 
                "PRODUCT"."NUMBER" DESC';

$query  = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query  ->bindParam(1 , $ofSearch);
$status = $query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Using question mark is a terrible way to do prepared statement as when you have very complex query with over 20 parameters it become a nightmare to maintain.

Do you have any idea if there is a solution to this problem or at least a workaround?

Comment: I think you may need to add "%".$ofSearch."%", can you try it

Comment: better to specify name in param $query  ->bindParam(":productNumber" , $ofSearch);

Comment: what is the driver you're using, may be also it is not supporting named parameter, chk Pdo SQL driver that allows for named parameters

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php, if this helps plz let me know to add and document an answer for your question

Comment: I'm trying to connect with dblib but I got the error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)" although the connection via CLI is working fine: tsql -S DBSERVER:PORT -U USER -P PASSWORD. Here is my PHP7.0 connexion string: $DBH = new PDO("dblib:Server=DBSERVER,PORT;Database=DB", 'USER', 'PASSWORD');